# Name the matrix (not the game show)

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix of the following form:

$
\begin{matrix}
a_1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
a_2 & a_1 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_n & a_{n-1} & \ldots & a_1
\end{matrix}
$

I'd like to know if this matrix has a special name (or even if it's a sum/product of special matrices).
The thing is, I need to build this matrix in matlab, and I could use some for loops, but I'd rather use some clean builtin functions.

Thanks

Edit: I just had a thought, maybe it can be a Vandermonde matrix times some other (unknown) matrix to nullify the terms above the diagonal...

Comment: Funny, I was [looking](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1020752/163) for the name Vandermonde matrix and thought of Toeplitz...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [lower triangular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_triangular_matrix) [Toeplitz matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).