# What is the name of the matrices of the form $(x_n^m)_{n,m}$?

Tags: matrices

I cannot remember but am almost certain matrices à la

\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots
\\1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots
\\1 & x_3 & x_3^2 & \cdots
\\\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}

have a special name and meaning, what is it?

Comment: @downvoter well please excuse the primitiveness of my question, it's been a couple of years since I studied and a matrix is rather difficult to even [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) let alone google >:-( or what else is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

It's interesting to remark that "no such expression occurs in Alexandre-Theophile Vandermonde's published writing"(From Ian Stewart's book Galois Theory), so the matrix gets its name for "obscure reasons"

Comment: That was quick, thanks :)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler You are welcome:)